# How to read a .sil (SmartInspect file) log file using c#

Tags: c#, readfile

I am currently using SmartInspect logging tool in my c# application, and now I am able to get the log files, and the log file is having extension ".sil" (ex:log-2013-04-04-08-22-05.sil"). Now my requirement is I need to read this log file from my c# application. I have tried all file reading concepts to read the log file but it's not working . Please suggests me a code how I will read the .sil file from a c# application.

When I am copying the file contents from SmartInspect logging tool and pasting in a normal txt file then it is working to get the file contents, but I am not able to read the .sil file using c# application.Please help...

Comment: Are you able to open and read using Notepad manually ?

Comment: There's a complete [format and specification](http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/smartinspect-log-formats-and-protocols.a.html) of this logfile format. You can use it to parse the logfile lines.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement your own Log file parser. The format of log file is documented here [`SmartInspect Log Formats and Protocols`](http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/smartinspect-log-formats-and-protocols.a.html)

SmartInspect uses its **`own format`** for ErrorLogging, as i noticed, i does not use `XML` or `Plain Text`

A typical `*.sil` file starts like

[image: typical sil file log]

You can use a free [`Redistributable Console`](http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/extras/) to read the file.

Comment: Technically, one could still implement a parser, but somehow I don't think the OP is up to it. Thanks for updating you answer ;)

Comment: Funny thing is, the redistributable console is of no value once the log file exceeds 2GiB - but the SDK should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

One of the SmartInspect developers here. We also have a ready-to-use SDK for .NET that allows you to read and process SmartInspect log files:

http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/extras/